# Groovy getProperty() on a static member

Tags: class, groovy, static, jvm, static-members

This question is probably going to illustrate a lack of knowledge on my part about how Groovy classes work, but I have tried to figure this out on my own with no luck. I want to create a getProperty() method on a class so I can reference member variables in a Groovyish way. This is NOT the same as just making them public because I do want some logic done when they are referenced. Basically, I'm trying to create a configuration Groovy class that uses ConfigSlurper:

```
class Configuration implements GroovyObject {
  private static ConfigObject config  = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("testing.conf").toURI().toURL())

  //This method is illegal, but it illustrates what I want to do
  public static String getProperty(String prop){
    config.getProperty(prop)
  }
}
```

If the above class were legal, I could then reference config items like so:

```
Configuration.dbUser
```

instead of this, which would require making the ConfigObject available:

```
Configuration.config.dbUser
```

I know, it would be worlds easier to just make the config object public, but knowing how to do this (or know why it's impossible) would help me understand Groovy a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can get it to work is via the metaClass:

```
class Configuration {
  private static ConfigObject config  = new ConfigSlurper().parse( "foo = 'bar'" )
}

Configuration.metaClass.static.propertyMissing = { name ->
  delegate.config[ name ]
}

println Configuration.foo
```

There may be a better way however...

Comment: Oh, you glorious man. That did it, thank you so much! I had tried the metaClass to define a getProperty static method, but that did not work. I can see what you did though, and it makes perfect sense. Since this is just for configuration stuff that isn't called very often, I'm okay with using this approach, but it IS expensive and is probably not suited for general use.